# How to dynamically change the number of days ago, using date in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a script that checks for request occurrences in a certain time window. My approach includes a variable `$daysAgo` that is decremented for every occurrence of the loop. What I don't understand is why the script bellow is giving me yesterdays date as output instead of 2 weeks ago. Any ideas?

```
#! /bin/bash
daysAgo=14
pastDate=$(date --date="($daysAgo) days ago" +%d/%b/%Y)
```

Comment: My answer edited to explain this...

Answer (score 1):

It worked as soon as I removed the parentheses

```
#! /bin/bash
daysAgo=14
pastDate=$(date --date="$daysAgo days ago" +%d/%b/%Y)
```

Comment: okay i got it to work..excellent thinking..I edited my answer to explain why this was so..

Answer (score 1):

**edited answer***

Enclosing the variable

> "$daysAgo"

with brackets will cause bash to interpret it as a subshell function (a function with its own local variables). any global variable in this case "$daysAgo" will not be substituted into the subshell function..think of the function like a separate script with codes and its own variables. removing the brackets as suggested will interpret the variable as a global variable